# Using Different SSL certificates per-location

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, certificate

I would like to serve different SSL certificates on my Apache webserver, depending on the location/URI requested. I don't want to serve the same SSL certificate for the entire VHost.

However, when I use `SSLCertificateFile` inside of `<Location>` and do a configtest, it fails: `AH00526: Syntax error on line 53 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my-site-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile not allowed here`

Is there a way to serve different SSL certificates, based on the location/request URI on the server?

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42718090/3395469).

Answer (score 0):

No, it makes little sense because the certificate is presented *before* the browser sends the URL.

(Think about it for a moment. If the certificate verification happened *after* sending the HTTP request, that would reveal the request – URL, headers cookies – to anyone who sets up a fake server, because once you get a fake certificate, you cannot "unsend" the request that you've already sent.)